# Magnesium powder + sodium carbonate solution: what happens?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I put magnesium powder into a sodium carbonate solution and it fizzed very slowly. The gas produced put out a lit splint immediately, which implies that carbon dioxide was released, but I cannot work out the equation for this reaction.

I'm fine with an acid plus a carbonate or a metal salt displacing another but this was just metal powder plus a carbonate.